# Will the stuff on my bootable drive save on the drive?

Tags: reboot, drive

I am new to linux, and ubuntu was the first thing I downloaded. I want to know that if I download something, i.e. Google Chrome, will it save if I restart my laptop or if I put my flash drive into another computer?
I use Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit on a bootable flash drive.

Comment: You can try Ubuntu in different ways (in a USB drive). See the following links and links from them, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312 -- *Persistent live drives* and *installed systems* (installed like into an internal drive but into a USB drive) can save data, application programs, tweaks, updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you partitioned your filesystem.

If your filesystem is on your hardrive in your laptop, the applications you download will be saved in your laptop, if your filesystem is on the pendrive, your application and application data will be saved in the pendrive.

What you install in your live CD will not be saved. However if you want to save your files, settings, applications etc.. You can follow [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) guide on creating a Live USB that is persistent.

Comment: How do I check where I partitioned it, and how do I change it?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on your laptop? Or are you trying to install google chrome from the live installation?

Comment: I haven't installed Ubuntu, I am using the first option where you can try it.

Comment: You will not be able to save your data in the trial mode. Unless you follow a specific way to make the USB persistent. Read my answer I edited it.