# Installing Ubuntu on a separate hard drive from Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I want to install Ubuntu and learn Linux.  I've been using Raspbian a bit and really would like to get away from Windows as much as possible.  The only problem is some of the games I use requires Windows for now.  Also, I'm taking classes through Coursera and using online tutorials to learn Linux from and would like an operating system installed besides the Raspbian I have on my Pi.

I have a desktop computer with Windows 10 installed on a SSD (M.2 if it matters) and another HDD used to store files. I have a new 1 TB HDD I'd like to install Ubuntu on. My plan is to install it and place the GRUB bootloader on the new drive.  I can then point the UEFI to that drive as the primary boot drive and GRUB should allow me to choose Linux or Windows. My thought is if I do this, I can change the boot order in UEFI back to C:\ drive and have the machine boot directly to Windows as it does now. Then I have the option of having a dual boot system or a Windows only system. Is this viable?  Should I use the whole drive for Linux?

Also, I'm reading a couple different opinions on disabling Secure Boot and Fast Boot from the UEFI.  Any reason not to disable these in my plan above?

Any other advice is welcome. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Your plan is feasible but unfortunately you don't understand UEFI. It's actually way more simple than that: You only need one ESP (EFI partition) regardless of where the second (or third or...) OS is installed. You can have more but for what you want to do that would be ridiculous. You can always boot Windows directly at UEFI boot settings and Ubuntu (Grub) no matter where Ubuntu is installed. One usually boots Grub (from Ubuntu) and from there select either Ubuntu (default) or Windows boot manager.

Comment: Re: settings, Fast Boot is optional but I usually disable it; Secure Boot can and should be disabled otherwise unsigned drivers won't load. You can keep Secure Boot but then you'll have to sign all such drivers by yourself and that's not for me let alone for a newbie. Ignore any different opinion from now on because I just told you everything you need to know and the only two options.

Comment: One issue is that Ubuntu's grub only installs to the ESP - efi system partition on sda. I have other installs on sdb and everytime they overwrite my working 16.04 boot on sda's ESP. With Windows they will share the ESP with different folder names. But I do like to have an ESP on every drive. Or if you disconnect all other drives then grub will install to that ESP. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 2):

### Independent drive with Ubuntu

It seems you want a 'complete' drive, that can you can boot into Ubuntu. Such a drive is independent of the drive with Windows, and you can make it according to the instructions at this link (it works for external and internal drives)

[Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

If you don't modify the ESP (EFI system partition) on the first internal drive `/dev/sda` , you can **press a hotkey to get a temporary boot menu**. And you can select to boot Ubuntu or Windows from this temporary menu.

### Standard installation

Otherwise let Ubuntu's installer automatically modify the ESP on the first internal drive `/dev/sda` and give you a grub menu.

This is what the Ubuntu's installer will do, when you install Ubuntu into a computer with another operating system. You can install Ubuntu into a partition or partitions in the same drive or in another drive.

It is possible to let the installer modify the partitions and create new partitions. It is also possible, and maybe easier, to use **gparted** to create the partitions you want before starting Ubuntu's installer.

---

So decide what you want, and if necessary ask about some details, and then go ahead.

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)