# Transfer all file and programs and settings to iso file

Tags: 14.04, 12.04

I have one ubuntu machine which I installed on it programs and settings such as(MySQL,PHP,freeradius ) and I configured this programs.
I developed freeradius management system on it so I want to export this system to iso file to be able to install it in another machine easily ,how can I do that ...

Comment: Is the method important, that you want to create an iso file? I am asking, because it is rather complicated to create a new iso file. It is easier to create an image of your current system, and such an image of an Ubuntu system is portable between computers. It is not as portable as what you can get with a well designed iso file, but often portable enough. You can start with the following links, https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you **Systemback** on your condition

The **Systemback** tool allows you to create restore points, backups, and live images of a running system.

## Installation

You won't find **Systemback** in the standard repositories, so you must first add the repo with the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nemh/systemback
```

Now, update apt with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install **Systemback** with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install systemback
```

You'll have to okay the dependencies before the install will begin. The dependencies will vary, based on what you have installed.

At this point, you should be able to start **Systemback** from the Unity Dash or your desktop start menu. You can also start **Systemback** from the command line with:

```
sudo systemback
```

You are now ready to create a live ISO.

## Usage

Using **Systemback** is quite easy. From the main window (**Figure A**), select the location to house the ISO image (by clicking the ... button under Storage Location).

**Figure A**
[image]
**Figure A**

**The Systemback main window.**

Click the Live system create button and, in the new window (**Figure B**), give the live system a name, change the storage location (this location will need to have more than 4 GB of available space), and click Create new. You can optionally include user data files by checking the associated box.

**Figure B**
[image]
**Figure B**

**Creating the live ISO image.**

*Note: If your .sblive file is larger than 4 GB, the conversion to a ISO is not possible. This is a file system limitation.*

Depending on the size of your installation, the process will take some time to complete, so grab a cup of coffee or administer a server or two. After it's installed, you should find an .sblive image in the defined storage location ready to convert to ISO. This image can either be written to a USB device or used to create a live ISO image. From the Created Live images window, select the image you want to convert, and then click Convert to ISO. When this process is completed, you'll find the .iso file in the storage location ready to be written to disk. With that disk, you can then install the live image on other machines.

The best time to use **Systemback** is on a close-to-newly installed system. This is simply because of the file system size limitation. If you've installed too many applications on the system, the size will reach beyond 4 GB, and you won't be able to convert it. You can, however, still create restore points for a system. To create a restore point, first make sure you've selected a Storage directory, and then click the Create New button.

Once you've created a restore point, you can then go back to that restore point by simply selecting it from the left side of the window (**Figure C**) and then clicking System Restore on the right side.

**Figure C**
[image]
**Figure C**

**Restoring from a restore point.**

In the resulting window (**Figure D**), select the type of restore you want to do, if you want to include user configuration files, and click Next. This will begin the restore process.

**Figure D**
[image]
**Figure D**

**Restore point options.**

Systemback is a great way to create live images based on a pre-existing system and restore points in case you need to roll a Linux machine backward.

[Source](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-live-system-iso-for-your-ubuntu-based-linux-machines-using-systemback/)

Comment: thank you for  your reply but can I install this live image into another machine or it will work live only without installation

Comment: The ISO file created with **Systemback** is intended to use on multiple machines. So, the answer is **YES**.

Comment: Keep in mind that, driver files may vary. So you might need to reinstall them.