# Ubuntu full installation portable

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, portable

Good night, i have a doubt:
When i use the LiveCD from Ubuntu it works on almost every PC, no matter what kind of hardware it has, but after installation, the S.O. makes some changes for adapt to hardware, ex. Netbook, desktop PC, wifi drivers, graphics, etc. 
I already installed Ubuntu on a USB Stick 32 GB but when i put it on other computer, the system try to load (the purple screen appear) but then crashes and some kind of weird stripes and other thins appear, the system boots, my both system specs.

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS x64

- **Laptop**: Intel Core i5 4120U with SSD Lite-on, 8 GB RAM and Nvidia GT-740M (i installed the SO from here)
- **Desktop** Intel Core i5 4590 with SSD Adata, 16 GB RAM and Nvidia GTX-970
  (i try booting here)

I need this installation (not live because i need some kind of software and tools and files and stuff like that persist and the "persist live" appears to reduce the USB Stick Lifetime) works on almost every kind of system like the way that LiveCD works on every pc. There is a way to install ubuntu using only this generic system? (without doing adapts for pc,laptop,drivers,etc)?. Greetings and i hope you could understand this.

Answer (score 2):

- **Ubuntu live (live-only or persistent live) is very portable as you know.**

  - You write *'the "persist live" appears to reduce the USB Stick Lifetime'.* It is true, but it is not as bad as it used to be with better quality of modern flash memory hardware. Furthermore, installed systems in a USB stick are also affected by excessive wear because of limited number of write cycles. I would even say that a persistent live system is less affected than an installed system (installed in the same USB stick), because it runs in RAM and only when saving new data, they are written to the casper-rw partition or file.
  - Links

    [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

    [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

    [Pendrive lifetime](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297)
- **Ubuntu can also be portable**, when installed in a USB stick (installed like into an internal drive, but into a USB stick (or HDD or SSD connected via USB or eSATA). But it is not as portable as when running live.

  - ***You should avoid proprietary drivers, typically for advanced graphics chips/cards and some wifi chips/cards.***

    You have Nvidia graphics, and I guess that you have installed a proprietary driver to run well in the computer, where you created the installed system in the USB drive. This driver might (will probably) create problems in computers with other graphics chips/cards. Even if it is the same brand, nvidia, it might need another proprietary driver.

    Sometimes you can get along with the free linux driver, `nouveau`, for nvidia graphics. But if it does not work in some of the computers, it will not be portable to those computers.
  - Link with detailed instructions how to create an installed system in an external drive (including tips to avoid excessive wear),

    [Boot Ubuntu from external drive.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)
- I suggest that you **try both a persistent live system (made with mkusb) and an installed system without proprietary drivers** and after some testing you can 
  decide which system is best for you.