# Software Center (on-persistent USB installation) asks for Ubuntu One login to install Chromium

Tags: usb, live-usb, ubuntu-one

I am running a lab (scratch, 7yo kids) on live USB installs (can't install Linux on the school machines), and suddenly I have to log into ubuntu-one to install Chromium from the app store.

Since there are no persistent USB installs anymore (at least in any of the usb creator programs), I have to log on on with my credentials for each machine in the lab (because I have a complex password that involves adding the lastpass extension to firefox, logging in lastpass and copying my password to the ubuntu-one login).

I doubt Ubuntu allows kids to sign the ubuntu-one agreement.

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 4):

### Persistent live system in a USB pendrive

You can create persistent live Ubuntu pendrives with mkusb. See these links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Install mkusb via PPA,

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

I would say that you need at least 4 GB USB pendrives. But to make the persistent live drives work well, you should have fast USB 3 pendrives, and you find no such drives below 16 GB. See this link

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)

See also the [mkUSB quick start manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)

[image]

### Installed system in a USB pendrive

You can install Ubuntu into a USB pendrive [almost] in the same way as you would install it into an internal drive.

- Advantages:
  You can

  - install hardware drivers and programs,
  - update and upgrade the system without any limits.
  - An installed system is more stable, less sensitive to corruption.
  - You can create an [OEM system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), to let the end users (students) configure the drives individually, which can be good if they share a local area network.
- Disadvantages:

  - Generally, an installed system in a USB pendrive is portable between computers, but not as portable as a [persistent] live system
  - If you install a proprietary driver (for example a graphics driver or wifi driver), the portability between different computers will be reduced.
  - The system is more sensitive to the read and write speed of the USB pendrive, it is more important to have a [fast USB 3 pendrive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed).

You find detailed instructions at the following link,

[Boot Ubuntu from external drive.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

Answer (score 2):

Windows boot drive makers with a persistence option include **UNetbootin**, **MultiBootUSB**, **YUMI** and **Universal**. YUMI and Universal are not limited to 4GB persistence.

Linux persistent boot drive makers include **mkusb**, which is my favorite, and MultiBootUSB, which has a 4GB persistence limit.

Have you considered doing a Full install to USB?

You can do an install, make it how you want it, adding programs, (like Chromium), etc, and then clone, image, or backup/restore the drive to the students USB drives. You could do this with a persistent mkusb install also.

Comment: +1 for the heads up about a 'full install to USB' and for the list of several tools :-)