# how to include more than 4gb .deb in custom ubuntu installation iso?

Tags: 16.04

File newIso/pool/extras/abcd.deb is larger than 4GiB-1.
-allow-limited-size was not specified. There is no way do represent this file size. Aborting

Comment: is there any way?

Comment: Maybe there is a workaround: You can create a persistent live drive with a casper-rw partition for persistence. Such a system will not be limited by any file size, only by the size of the USB pendrive. (It means that you do not include the big file in the iso file, but 'later on' so that it will be stored in the partition for persistence.) You can try according to these links, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent

Comment: That is HUGE. There is probably a better way of making your custom iso.

Comment: It is also possible to make an **installed system**, that can be portable enough between different computers. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312