# Xubuntu 16.04 installed on USB stick dont't boot after power loss

Tags: boot, xubuntu, usb-drive

Several times i have installed xubuntu 16.04 on 2 adata s102 32GB usb sticks. OS boots every time i use restart command or shutdown command and then power on button. After i turn off power supply (when pc is shutdown) BIOS doesn't see usb stick as bootable. I've tried to boot on 2 different computers. Please help.

Comment: I have not seen this happen with my USB sticks. But I have no Adata sticks. Maybe they have some special feature - that they can be doing some internal administration tasks, that were interrupted, when you turned off power. I have noticed similar problems with hard disk drives connected via USB, and in those cases they worked again after repairing the file system (for example according to this link), https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986

Comment: Good luck, and let us know the result :-)

Comment: Unfortunately commands sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb2 or sudo e2fsck -cfk /dev/sdb2 or install-mbr /dev/sdb didn't help. I think there is a problem with MBR in this model of ADATA USB sticks. Tomorrow i'll try on another USB stiks.

Comment: You can try from the beginning according to the following link and links from it. I make installed systems in USB drives that way, and they are portable between most (but not all) of my computers, https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312; and they work after power off with my USB sticks (for example Sandisk, Transcend and Kingston).