# Installed FULL Ubuntu on USB, boots up, but not on other computers

Tags: boot, usb

I had two USB sticks plugged into the computer. An empty 16GB stick which I planned to install FULL Ubuntu on, 8GB stick with live Ubuntu and installer. I followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIhYitXwJfE) on how to install full Ubuntu on a USB.

When I checked to see if the 16GB USB works on other computers, I found that I get `no operating system found` and the the system on the internal drive (Windows) boots. It only works on the computer I used to install Ubuntu on, but not the others. Hmmm...

Is there another method of installing FULL Ubuntu on a USB stick?

Comment: Another possibility is that the bootloader did not get installed in the right place. This happens quite often if the internal drive has not been disabled prior to installation.

Answer (score 3):

An installed system is portable between computers, but not as portable as a live or persistent live system. Things to check:

- Avoid proprietary drivers.
- Usually an installed system will work either in UEFI mode or BIOS mode, not both. But it is possible to make a system that can boot in both modes, as described in [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS).
- Check that the system is compatible with the computer hardware. 32-bit Ubuntu works in both 32-bit and 64-bit hardware, but 64-bit Ubuntu needs 64-bit hardware.
- Check that the bootloader was installed in the USB drive (and not in the internal drive), as suggested in the comment by @C.S.Cameron.

The following link and links from it can give you several tips that help you make a portable Ubuntu system, that will work in the computers, where you want to run it.

[Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

Comment: "But it is possible to make a system that can boot in both modes.". One question one word: How? :)

Comment: @Videonauth, It is described in this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS

Comment: Sad, not very usable for my case, seems I have to research into it more. Need a way to make the MBR and EFI on the fly for my tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, will read into that, if you're interested of which tutorial I speak of you can check my profile for my blog link.

Comment: @Videonauth, The quick fix method is to extract a compressed image. My basic method is to switch between the boot modes and install the corresponding grub versions to install the bootloaders for each mode. If you want to make a tutorial with an 'on the fly method', you could do something between my image of a complete system of the UEFI-and-BIOS link and what is used in mkusb, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Method_developed_from_.27grub-n-iso.27, 'Cloning the head end', and 'diy', https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy

Comment: @Videonauth, I did not find the tutorial, please link to it :-)

Comment: Well: https://videonauth.dyndns.org/index.php/2016/05/26/tutorial-how-to-install-ubuntu-and-other-debian-based-distributions-via-debootstrap/ here it is, the link to it is in my profile tho. :) I'm actually in the process of a complete re-write of that ans want to add 1. Efi installation, bios installation and dual installation, and of course fix the incorrect part about setting the language ;)

Comment: Whenever I do a Full install to USB, the device boots both BIOS and UEFI, at least with 16.04 and later. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, On the contrary. Please tell us how you manage to do that, to make it boot in both modes :-P

Comment: @Sudodus: I generally work in BIOS mode. I am in UEFI mode at present booted from a Lexar 128G Ultra with a GPT table made using the step by step on the duplicated question on a BIOS boot. Yesterday I made an install of Elementary OS with a msdos partition table while booted BIOS and it has no problem with UEFI. Maybe my computer's UEFI is funky... Anything you want me to test? I used mkusb to make the Live disks.

Comment: I think the UEFI in my HP EliteBook is not typical, it does not work in other computers in UEFI mode. see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: Above mentioned link by me changed to https://videonauth.ddns.net.