# Can't unpack self-extractable archive with Mathematica

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, archive, mathematica

I try to install Mathematica from script on Lubuntu Next 17.10. I run

`$ bash Mathematica_11.2.0_LINUX.sh`

it successfully verifies the archive integrity and starts installer extraction process. A few seconds later it stops and if I don't intervene at this point killing the process via Ctrl-Z, but choose to wait some time instead, my computer freezes and I have to do hard reset.

I tried to run it with sudo, that didn't make any difference.

Lubuntu is installed to the single partition and there is plenty of free space (more than 400 GB).

I verified checksums and saw no differences.

I'll be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Please check where you downloaded Mathematica, which linux distros and versions to use. Lubuntu Next is experimental. Maybe you have better luck with standard Lubuntu 17.10 or Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: @sudodus You're right, Lubuntu Next is not on the list of the supported OSes. However, I find it hard to believe it is so much different from normal flavours that a standard archive can't be unpacked (were it a problem with installation itself, it would be another story).

Comment: Lubuntu Next is experimental (still being developed),  There are things that do not work. I suggest that you try with a supported OS according to the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install issue: Mathematica 9 on Ubuntu 13.10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42535/install-issue-mathematica-9-on-ubuntu-13-10).

Comment: @sudodus Thank you, I see your suggestion as the last resort in nothing else works out (it means, I'll have to re-install not just OS but a lot of other stuff as well).

Comment: @J. Starnes I have already found that post and have tried the suggested workaround. No luck, did not work for me.

Comment: You can make a quick test to install Mathematica in a live or persistent live system (booted from a USB pendrive). That way you can test things without overwriting your current Lubuntu Next system. You can use mkusb to create the live or persistent live system, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb ; If you try this, you should check how much drive space you need, and if there is enough RAM for a live-only system or enough drive space for the casper-rw partition for a persistent live system to accommodate Mathematica.

Comment: An alternative is an installed system in a USB drive according to this link and links from it, https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312