# I am trying to install ubuntu using a flash drive as a hard drive

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive, portable

New to Ubuntu. I am trying to install ubuntu on an older computer (2004ish) using a flash drive as the hard drive. I can boot to ubuntu without any problems, but when I go to install it, it fails to create swap and doesn't let me continue the installation. I am using a 32 gig flash drive, and partitioning it 5G to /, and 5G to swap, with the rest as free space. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest that you use more drive space for root (/). For example, you can let the computer use the whole flash drive (and decide the sizes of the partitions automatically). You can try according to the following link, [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312) -- But there is also another problem. Such an old computer will probably have difficulties to run standard Ubuntu. Instead I suggest an Ubuntu community flavour with a light-weight desktop environment, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu.

Comment: Just want to clarify, 1) does the flash drive also contain the Ubuntu installer, or do you have a Live CD? 2) Did you create the partitions for root and swap before attempting to install? I ask bc from my experience, these partitions must be created before starting the installation process. The installer is supposed to be able to create partitions but I have never gotten this to work & always make mine in gparted beforehand. Also as @sudodus pointed out you should allocate more space for root since you want to do a full install. Also agree lububtu/xubuntu should be used given the constraints