# Ubuntu 16.04 Persistent - Installing Nvidia Proprietary drivers(Post Login Loop)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I want to do light gaming with my GT 710. So I went I ahead and installed the proprietary drivers through GUI method. I got a login Loop. I fixed the loop but now I want to install the drivers without getting the loop. What do you guys suggest to do?

Comment: Have you tried the answers here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers  ?

Comment: You can not install the nvidia driver in persist mode you would have to remaster the iso. Persistence is a way to access data but does not act as a normal installation

Comment: You can make an **installed system in a USB drive** (installed like into an internal drive). See this link, [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312). You can install a proprietary driver in this system (and it will work in computers, that work with that driver, but maybe not in other computers).

Answer (score 0):

What finally fixed the problem for me was disabling the UEFI secure boot option for my OS:

1. Enter your UEFI Bios utility on boot and navigate to advanced mode.
2. Disable fast boot
3. Go to boot/secure boot and change OS type to "Other OS"
4. Save and restart

http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable

Comment: To prevent the effects of link-rot, would you please show the basic steps?