# MBR or GPT partition when making ubuntu bootable live usb

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, uefi, gpt, mbr

I just want to clarify.
When making the ubuntu live usb using Rufus, do we select:

1. **GPT partition scheme for UEFI**
2. **MBR partition scheme for UEFI**

I currently have windows 10 pro installed and would like to make a dual boot system by installing ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10 pro.

I am currently following these steps for my installation:

https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Update:

I had tried to boot into the usb but it hang at the login screen. Anyone have any idea how to solve this? Really running out of ideas to try. I think 16.04.4 ubuntu image iso is faulty. I am thinking of downgrading back to 16.04.3 to see if it works.

Also another side question -- do we need nvidia drivers to be the same in Windows 10 and also in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Adding on, from the ubuntu website: 

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3

It is recommmended that we create the live usb with **MBR partition for UEFI** so I am a bit confuse as to which partition scheme to use

Comment: Most probably your partition table would be GPT as Windows 10 is already installed. Go for GPT partition scheme for UEFi

Comment: If you're talking about the USB itself, then MBR should be more than sufficient. PS you're following instructions for Ubuntu 14.04, not 16.04?

Comment: @Xen2050 -- the methode of setting up dual boot are the same regardless of version, or even distro.

Comment: @ravery I read that Ubuntu can work with secure boot enabled now, usually. But in general just noticed the 14.04 url, while it's almost time for 18.04

Comment: @Xen2050, So the current link I posted is not for the correct ubuntu version? Where can I get the link for 16.04?

Comment: @ravery Just to add one to the question, the purpose of choosing the partition table is so that our workstation can read and boot from the usb right?

Comment: I had heard good things about the current dual boot system with 16.04 and windows 10 pro so I would like to give it a try. Very excited to start playing with ubuntu!

Comment: the purpose of a partition table is so there can be more than one partition on the device. It is possible to format a device without a partition table. In theory UEFI should be able to boot from it, if formated to FAT and there is an EFI folder; however in practice,  it would vary by system.

Comment: Please create a new AskUbuntu question about the nvidia drivers, or search for AskUbuntu questions with useful answers, for example [the links in my second comment in this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017662/nvdia-ubunutu-blackscreen) to a current question at AskUbuntu.

Comment: You can use both, unless your computer is very old.
And you may need to change your BIOS settings in order to allow the computer to boot from a MBR or GPT USB disk.

Answer (score 4):

UEFI can boot from either partition scheme. Since, a USB is generally small, and you are just making a live installer. either can be used equally as well.

If you want some basic information about the difference see here:
https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Some_basics_of_MBR_v/s_GPT_and_BIOS_v/s_UEFI

Answer (score 4):

### Partition table

If you are talking about a **live** Ubuntu system, yes, MBR alias MSDOS partition table is recommended, for example if you use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) in Windows. Rufus is an extracting tool with a good reputation.

---

If you are talking about an [**installed** Ubuntu system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312) (like into an internal drive, but in this case in a USB drive), then you can select both MBR alias MSDOS partition table and GPT alias GUID partition table, but it will be easier with MBR.

### Cloning the ISO 9660 system

But if you **clone** from an Ubuntu iso file to the USB pendrive, you need not worry about the boot sector/method, everything will be cloned, and you get a 'hybrid' system with an ISO 9660 system which includes the boot sector 'automatically'. The cloning method is very reliable and will create a **live** (live-only) Ubuntu system, that can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (CSM alias legacy mode).

Cloning tools in linux:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer: Startup Disk Creator
- Disks alias `gnome-disks`
- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) (install from a PPA)

Cloning tool in Windows:

- [Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)

Comment: *Why* is MBR recommended for a live Ubuntu system? If I'm not planning on booting the live USB except for on computers that have UEFI firmware, then is there anything wrong with selecting the GPT option in Rufus instead of MBR? GPT is better than MBR when it comes to UEFI support. Does that translate into GPT is better than MBR for making a live USB with Rufus assuming that I don't want to boot the live USB on a legacy BIOS computer?