# NVIDIA 1060ti + Ubuntu 16.04 = Black screen

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I installed an Nvdia driver in Ubuntu 16.04. I have Nvdia 1060ti. I don't know how to enter through recovery mode. I tried every solution in this forum but I ended up with a black screen or screen freeze. Can you help me with this issue?

I came to this because Blender was not functioning properly.

Comment: Have you tried with the **boot option `nomodeset`** ? If it gives you a working but simple graphics screen, you can continue and try with some nvidia proprietary driver for your graphics card.

Comment: Can you guide me with this step by step? I would be thankfull...

Comment: The first step: boot with the boot option `nomodeset`: See the following link and links from it, [Boot options](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808); The second step: See the following link (the accepted answer with a green mark) and links from it, [Black screen with nVidia drivers on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450046/black-screen-with-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: I am stuck since I am not able to use boot option nomodeset.. after i know what to do to use better gpu but i am stuck before going to that phase.. actually i got idea how to use nomodeset..thanks a lot.. i was unaware about the method...i am searching the correct way to use nomodeset...

Comment: What about this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808 and links from it? If you get no grub menu in an installed system, you can try pressing the left 'upper-case' key during boot.

Comment: I went to linux line and replaced 'quite splash' with 'nomodeset' and pressed 'ctrl x' but i could not boot.

Comment: That is the way to do it. If `nomodeset` does not work, you have to try something else, **some other boot option might do it** depending on your hardware. Please tell us about it, you can start with **the computer's brand name and model**.

Comment: Dell inspiron 7577... nvdia 1060ti...

Comment: This seems to be a new computer. It means that you probably have better luck with the newest possible versions of Ubuntu, 17.10.1 or 'Bionic', which is still in the development phase, to be released April 2018 as 18.04 LTS. You can find 17.10.1 via the official [Ubuntu web site](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and [Bionic via the ISO testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/384/builds/168505/downloads).

Comment: I am.using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Yes, and I suggest that you download, check with `md5sum` and create a boot drive of the *two newer versions* that I suggested in my previous comment. Dell computers are usually working well with Ubuntu (but I don't know your model). -- But even with the new versions you will probably need `nomodeset` because of the nvidia graphics.

Comment: I found solution on my own...to.reboot.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be helpful... I installed Nvidia driver and restarted my computer. I got black screen in loop. The solution is to use other graphic card to boot. Cd or usb is not required for this. My solution is:

1. As computer starts keep on pressing left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
2. In order to edit grub2 press <kbd>e</kbd>.
3. Then go to line starting with `linux` and enter `i915.modeset=0` before `quite slash`.

   Since my choice was to use the Intel graphic card. I inserted that line. If it was amd/ati, `radeon.modeset=0` could work. In some computer simply inserting `nomodeset` may work.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to reboot.
5. Then wait for a while... After screen freezes press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
6. It asks for username and password. Enter them.
7. Then terminal appears. Uninstall NVdia drivers using
   the command:

   ```
    sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
   ```
8. Then type `reboot`... then your Ubuntu will  boot...

This solution is just to enter the OS. Now follow proper method to install NVidia driver for better graphics.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way (that I used recently) to recover from wrong video driver and black screen is to use the option [Try Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) from an installation CD/USB. Then mount your root file system and use `chroot` to work against it instead of the live Ubuntu in RAM, and at this point purge the driver.

1. Boot from Ubuntu installation media and choice Try Ubuntu.
2. Find which is the partition where Ubuntu is installed (if it is [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) you should use `/dev/<volume group>/<volume name>`). Let's assume it is `/dev/sda1` for the example.
3. Open new terminal window and mount this partition to the directory `/mnt`:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
4. Then use `mount` to `--bind`: `/dev` to `/mnt/dev`, `/proc` to `/mnt/proc` and `/sys` to `/mnt/sys`:

   ```bsh
   for f in dev proc sys ; do mount --bind /$f /mnt/$f ; done
   ```
5. Then change the root directory:

   ```bsh
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
6. At this pint purge the NVidia driver:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
   ```
7. Exit from the `chroot`, unmount and reboot the system:

   ```bsh
   exit
   sudo umount /mnt/sys
   sudo umount /mnt/proc
   sudo umount /mnt/dev
   sudo umount /mnt
   sudo systemctl reboot
   ```

References:

- [Ubuntu - Blinking cursor and cannot start after Nvidia driver upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/651596/ubuntu-12-04-lts-blinking-cursor-and-cannot-start-after-nvidia-driver-upgrade/651597#651597) (this is the main source of the current answer).
- [Is there an easier way to chroot than bind-mounting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32418/is-there-an-easier-way-to-chroot-than-bind-mounting)

Comment: I dont have cd..

Comment: @ShresthaBibash - nor USB? Sadly. If it is possible to access the [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) you could purge the driver from there.

Comment: Is there any option by using nomodeset boot?

Comment: @ShresthaBibash: It could do the job in some cases. But some NVidia drivers makes the system insensitive to this option.  I've tried to use nomodeset to deal with the wrong resolution within the TTYs (`ctrl + alt + F1` to `F6`), but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @ShresthaBibash, please write your own answer when you have a time. It would be useful for other people with the same problem.