# Terminal does not appear and package management is broken after I removed python3.5 and installed python3.6

Tags: gnome-terminal, python3, anaconda

Recently I removed python3.5 and installed python3.6 using conda. Now terminal doesn't start and I can see a red error button at top right corner that says

> A Problem occurred when checking for the updates

How can I fix it?

Comment: check if there are other  terminals such as `xterm`

Comment: xterm is there but how to make terminal appear?

Comment: most probably your `~/.bashrc` file got corrupted.

Comment: @kenn nope. This is caused by deleting the system default python, which is a dependency of gnome-terminal and a whole bunch of other important stuff. Removing the pre-installed python is a really easy way to wreck Ubuntu

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: if it's a broken dependency problem, `sudo apt-get install -f` via `xterm` should work

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.04. I installed python3.6 again but is not working

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default

Comment: If any other suggestion doesn't provide solution, you can try to boot from live USB, mount your file system and `chroot` to it. Then you should be able to reinstall the packages. Here is step-by-step manual (just change the commands in step 6): https://askubuntu.com/a/1017682/566421

Comment: 17.04 is unsupported, so you need to upgrade to fix any package management issue - see [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](//askubuntu.com/q/91815)

Comment: @Zanna IMHO he might be better of doing a fresh install with a newer Ubuntu version, my reason for this advise is, 17.10 is already gnome based and the changes are manifold, and while hes anyways on it he could directly install 18.04 which is meanwhile very stable. And foremost without working Python he might not even be able to do the release upgrade anyway.

Comment: I am upgrading from 17.04 to 18.04. Let's see it works or not.