# MSI laptop install Ubuntu 17.10 on pendrive

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, usb-installation, msi

I have laptop MSI GP70 and I am able to boot installation from first USB stick and install it on second USB stick, then when I want to boot installed system from second USB drive I am unable to do so, even pressing F11 this drive is not listed in possible boot drives... on the other hand I am able to boot this USB on other laptop without UEFI and MSI stuff - any ideas how to boot this pendrive in MSI laptop?

---

additional: maybe if there were possibility to create EFI partition to boot system then it would solve problem?

---

**Solution**
I had problem a problem getting into bios (DEL key but it's pure luck when to click to reach bios) it turned out that my 32GB SanDisk USB drive was HDD Drive and this option wasn't set in BIOS now it's ok - also I turned boot option from UEFI to LEGACY and it worked

Comment: **1.** If you can unplug your internal drive, it will not be tampered with, when you install Ubuntu into a USB drive (pendrive, SSD or HDD). See this link for more details, [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312) ; **2.** If you are happy with 16.04 LTS, you can get it 'directly' by [expanding and cloning a compressed image file according to this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS). This version works in both UEFI and BIOS mode.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)  As a matter of fact, you can *put your solution into an answer, and 'accept' it.* This will indicate in the  'AskUbuntu way' that you have solved the problem.

Comment: will do it tomorrow :) thx for info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problem a problem getting into bios (DEL key but it's pure luck when to click it to reach bios) it turned out that my 32GB SanDisk USB drive was "USB HDD Drive" instead of "USB Key" and this option wasn't set in BIOS now it's ok - also I turned boot option from UEFI to LEGACY and it worked

Answer (score -2):

Ah, a full USB installation, my old nemesis. Often times, when you install Ubuntu on a USB flash drive, it can screw up your Grub on your main hard drive (even when you tell it not too). A sure fire way to get a full installation on a USB flash drive with no hassle, damage, or issue, is to do it through a Virtual Box. Else it can be risky and time consuming. What could have happened is that it put Grub on the hard drive and it then points to the USB to boot it but it won't boot if you transfer it to another computer.

Comment: I am interested in booting from usb since I want to write code on my old laptop and run it on my brothers new laptop which is much more powerful (GPU) thus any VM solution is not feasible... also he has windows I have linux and I want to change as little as possible on his laptop

Comment: Not quite, you would use a VM to install it on the USB without risking the laptop, the goal of the Virtual Machine is temporary use in order to install Ubuntu on the USB device. After which you should have an independent full install on a USB device able to boot on most computers (depending on 32 or 64 bit and BIOS and UEFI)

Comment: like I said in question "I am able to boot this USB (with installed system) on other laptop without UEFI and MSI stuff" but I am unable on MSI laptop...

Comment: Alright, and which computer did you use in order to install Ubuntu on the USB stick. Did you use your "MSI" computer or this "other" laptop

Comment: @sudodus this is completely true and will work. Might not be the easiest thing to do however as it's a laptop but still a good option

Comment: It is very different between laptops. In my Toshiba, there is only one screw that is holding the lid covering the bay for the SATA HDD/SSD. Some laptops are more complicated to open, and in some computers the internal drive is soldered to the motherboard. Some computers have UEFI/BIOS systems, that let you disable the internal drive, which is also a good option.