# how much size required for booting ubuntu in usb?

Tags: usb

I am new to install ubuntu. I want to install it using boot able usb. My question is how much size usb drive required for making bootable ubuntu operating operating system?

Comment: You need to write the Ubuntu iso image you download onto it, which is roughly 1.5GB large. So, a 2GB USB stick is enough.

Comment: You don't really need a USB stick, you can use a cell phone or MP3 player, or etc.

Answer (score 4):

### Edit 2023-03-18: Heads up

**{** Please notice that Ubuntu Desktop and its community flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) grow. **Each new version comes with a bigger iso file**. Lately they grow faster than ever, mainly because some tools are distributed as **snaps**.

This means that you need bigger USB drives. The [next version of Ubuntu Desktop to be released as 23.04 next month](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) will need an 8GB USB drive (the iso file exceeds 4GB), unless it will be trimmed down during the last few weeks before release.

Most community flavours, particularly the light-weight Lubuntu and Xubuntu continue to be small enough to fit when cloned to 4 GB pendrives.

Ubuntu Server grows too, but slowly compared to the desktop versions/flavours.
**}**

---

### USB drive size 2 GB - Ubuntu live-only

As @ByteCommander indicates, a 2GB USB pendrive or memory card (connected via a USB adapter) will be big enough for a live-only USB boot drive, that you can use to 'Try Ubuntu' or Install Ubuntu into another drive (an internal drive or another USB drive).

There are more details at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_size).

### USB drive size 4 GB - Ubuntu persistent live

A 4GB USB pendrive or memory card (connected via a USB adapter) will be big enough for a persistent live USB boot drive.

There are more details at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent).

### USB drive size 16 GB - Ubuntu installed system

A 16GB USB pendrive or memory card (connected via a USB adapter) will be big enough for an installed system in a USB boot drive (installed like into an internal drive).

There are more details at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312).

### General link

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

### Edit 2023-02-20:

The iso files are growing quickly and the information above is no longer relevant for the newest versions of Ubuntu. I think the main reason for the growth is the *snap* system.

- Generally, we need **USB drive size 8 GB** nowadays for standard Ubuntu Desktop.

This is illustrated by the following listing of some iso files that I have downloaded. Please notice that some of them exceed 4 GB.

I have used my shellscript `newfiles` looking for the files touched in my computer during the latest 600 days.

```
newfiles 600 /media/multimed-2/test/ubuntu {18,20,22}.04 -name '*.iso' | sort -nk5 | cut -d ' ' -f 5-
695205888   2018-04-26_21.58 '18.04/xubuntu-18.04-core-amd64.iso'
851443712   2021-10-15_19.38 '18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso'
855638016   2021-09-09_16.42 '20.04/ubuntu-20.04.1-legacy-server-amd64.iso'
866123776   2020-09-18_06.56 '/media/multimed-2/test/ubuntu/focal-legacy-server-amd64.iso'
1200881664  2021-08-05_10.18 '18.04/lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso'
1235918848  2022-05-06_16.50 '22.04/xubuntu-22.04-core-amd64.iso'
1261371392  2021-12-29_17.03 '20.04/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso'
1261371392  2021-09-28_10.14 '20.04/persistent-ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso'
1406533632  2022-09-08_07.32 '/media/multimed-2/test/ubuntu/focal-live-server-amd64.iso'
1466714112  2022-04-23_08.38 '22.04/ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso'
1474873344  2022-08-09_16.48 '22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso'
1507780608  2022-09-07_09.56 '/media/multimed-2/test/ubuntu/jammy-live-server-amd64.iso'
1932853248  2022-05-03_18.54 '20.04/lubuntu-20.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso'
1996488704  2022-08-31_07.14 '20.04/lubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso'
2475399168  2022-08-10_18.35 '22.04/xubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'
2606266368  2022-04-19_10.17 '22.04/lubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
2688100352  2022-08-09_12.03 '22.04/lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'
2701512704  2022-04-21_21.05 '22.04/xubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
2865117184  2022-04-19_10.16 '22.04/ubuntu-budgie-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
2877227008  2021-08-11_15.30 '20.04/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso'
2918014976  2022-04-19_10.21 '22.04/ubuntu-mate-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
3379068928  2022-07-30_21.06 '20.04/ubuntu-20.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso'
3412525056  2022-05-05_08.28 '/media/multimed-2/test/ubuntu/focal-desktop-amd64.iso'
3654957056  2022-04-19_10.25 '22.04/ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
3674746880  2022-04-19_10.22 '22.04/kubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
3826831360  2022-08-11_16.53 '22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'
4448057344  2022-04-19_10.28 '22.04/ubuntustudio-22.04-dvd-amd64.iso'
4931569664  2022-04-23_08.41 '22.04/ubuntukylin-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
4939010048  2023-02-07_07.31 '/media/multimed-2/test/ubuntu/jammy-desktop-amd64.iso'
5894375424  2023-02-11_08.16 '/media/multimed-2/test/ubuntu/lunar-desktop-amd64.iso'
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be minimum 2 GB. You can follow tutorials on Official Ubuntu Installation Page.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows