# How can I make settings persistant on Ubuntu on USB flash drive

Tags: live-usb

I have created a bootable USB on Ubuntu. I opened it and made some changes like keyboard settings, creating new text files so on. After restarting Ubuntu all settings and files are gone. Is there any solution for this? What must I do?

Comment: See these links,
[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389) and
[mkusb - persistent live](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) and
[Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312) and
[how much size required for booting ubuntu in usb?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018478/how-much-size-required-for-booting-ubuntu-in-usb/1018489#1018489) and the [do it yourself method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy)

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of install to a USB stick.

1) Normal is is like a LiveCD. When you reboot, any "changes" are lost.

2) With Persistence is like having a Home partition on the stick. You can save SOME stuff to the persistent partition. Not everything will be saved.

3) A full install. If your USB is big enough. All changes should be saved.

Comment: how should ı try to do 2 or 3 options. I just used rufus exe and booed image on it.

Comment: The question is "How to make persistence settings flash USB on Ubuntu" not what is one, this does not answer the question -1

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb

Comment: it was very clear explanation, metodology also.

Comment: ı tried to use some programs for persistence when job done ı couldnt start with usb on boot. normally after boot on usb it works.

Comment: ı used for persistence LiLi, universal usb installer ,PDL-Casper-RW