# Installing KDE on Ubuntu, fails to fetch files because of versions mismatches

Tags: apt, kde, versions

Trying to install KDE on Ubuntu 16.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

I do **not** get to the selection of the display manager.

I have a list of errors like:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby2.3/ruby2.3_2.3.1-2~16.04.5_amd64.deb
 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

Going on the corresponding http page, I see this file with a slightly different version number:

```
ruby2.3_2.3.1-2~16.04.6_amd64.deb
```

How can I install KDE if there is no exact match between the packages' versions?

---

The answers to [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) do not seem to cover my case, i.e. with most packages correctly installed, but with some not found due to minor version mismatches.

Comment: I suggest that you try Kubuntu separately (avoid mixing different desktop environments). Start by testing it *live*, 'Try Kubuntu', and if you like it and want to install it, create a dual boot or multi boot system with separate partitions (or drives) for Ubuntu and Kubuntu. You can share the swap partition.

Comment: @karel: in the question you linked, I could not find my case, i.e. when there is not an exact match in the version numbers.

Comment: @sudodus - I cannot install a different version of Linux. I can only upgrade the current Ubuntu installation (it is not my computer).

Comment: I see. Why do you or the owner of the computer want KDE alongside the desktop environment of standard Ubuntu? And why not install `kubuntu-desktop` from the Ubuntu repositories (without any PPA)? (But I would not do it.)

Comment: An alternative is to try Kubuntu *live* or *persistent live* booted from a USB pendrive. That is rather easy and will not tamper with the current Ubuntu installed system.

Comment: @sudodus - Many users prefer KDE, so we need both environments, and using a live distribution is not an option.

Comment: @sudodus - How can I install KDE without PPA? Is what I did (see question) correct?

Comment: You can install kubuntu-desktop, but it will bring a lot of KDE application programs (the whole bunch of Kubuntu applications). I do not know which packages to install to get as little as possible, yet a working desktop. Let us hope someone else can help you. If no luck here, you can start a thread at the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org).

Comment: @sudodus - I do want to install the whole KDE, and most of its applications.

Comment: You may need to remove the packages you have installed via the PPA before removing the PPA, and then remove the PPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### System with standard Ubuntu (with Unity) and a KDE desktop

This way you can get a system with standard Ubuntu (with Unity) and a KDE desktop, where you can select desktop environment at the login screen by clicking on the cog wheel symbol.

- Install Ubuntu from `ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso`
- Make the system up to date with

  ```
  sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```
- Install KDE-related packages

  ```
  sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop
  sudo apt install kde-runtime
  sudo apt install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop
  ```

  It might work too, if you use only the last line (I did not test that), but if you use it without `--no-install-recommends` there will be at least one serious conflict. The installation will fail, and there will be a black screen with a cursor instead of the KDE desktop. (Standard Ubuntu will still work.)

  [image]

  You can see that there are gnome application programs available via the KDE menu. But because of `--no-install-recommends`, several Kubuntu application programs are not installed. (Most of them can probably be installed, but it is was not done in this test.)

### Alternatives

According to a comment, you don't want a live or persistent live system, but please consider the following alternatives.

- **Dual boot** with separate Ubuntu system and Kubuntu system. Both systems are complete and can use the full power of the computer.
- Ubuntu host system and **Kubuntu guest system in a virtual machine**. It is easiest to use VirtualBox to create the virtual machine. Both systems are complete, but the Kubuntu guest system cannot use the full power of the computer. This can be a good solution in a powerful computer.
- Installation of [**Kubuntu in a USB SSD drive**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312).Both systems are complete and Kubuntu can use almost the full power of the computer (a little slower than if in an internally connected SSD).