# Live USB image can't boot after running out of memory on persistence file

Tags: boot, 17.10, live-usb

I created a **live Ubuntu** on a SanDisk 32GB USB-stick using 
[LiLi](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/) with
[Ubuntu 17.10.1](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10.1/ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso). During the creation I chose to have a persistance layer of 4GB. After running a couple of recoveries from the stick, the persistence layer **filled up completely (no space left on device)**. Now Ubuntu is booting up to the point where it should ask if we want to install or try Ubuntu. The **dialog is empty** except the points that indicate the different pages in it. At this point, the network is connected, but it's not possible to continue to the live system.
Using `Ctrl+Alt+F[1-10]` is not bringing up any login shells.
I assume this is due to the completely full persistence layer (casper-rw if I'm correct).
Is there any possibility to either:

1. **Boot up the system?**
2. **Access the files on the persistence layer?**

Answers are much appreciated because it took ~13h to create the file index from a broken disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mount casper-rw file, (booting from a second drive).

Create directory:

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper
```

Then mount drive:

```
sudo mount -o loop casper-rw /media/casper/
```

After a few files are removed Persistent drive should boot.

If you need more persistence space, you can create a home-rw persistence file up to 4GB, (by copying and renaming a casper-rw file). It can contain all your home folder data, or you can make the boot drive using mkusb which uses an unlimited casper-rw partition.

If you will be needing to update or upgrade your boot drive it is probably best to do a Full install to the drive.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with C.S.Cameron, and I will add some details and links.

Steps to more space for persistence:

- Create a `home-rw` persistence file up to 4GB and move your current home from `casper-rw` to this partition in your current persistent live system.

  - Boot from another drive (or the same one, but live-only without the boot option `persistent`).
  - Create directories to become mountpoints.
  - Mount `casper-rw` and `home-rw`, for example to the mountpoints `/media/casper-rw` and `/media/home-rw`.
  - Then you can use `rsync` to copy `/home` like so (first a dry run, then remove the `n` and do the job),

    ```
    sudo rsync -Havn /media/casper-rw/upper/home/ /media/home-rw  # dry run

    sudo rsync -Hav /media/casper-rw/upper/home/ /media/home-rw   # do the job
    ```

    The trailing slash in  `.../upper/home/` is important, see `man rsync`.
  - When you have checked that persistence is working from `home-rw`, you can remove the `/media/casper-rw/upper/home` directory tree.
- Create a new persistent live system with a partition labeled `casper-rw` for persistence (and if you wish also a partition labeled `home-rw`.

  See these links: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and [mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

  [image]
- Install Ubuntu (like into an internal drive) but to a USB drive,

  See this link: [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

If you intend to keep the Ubuntu system on the USB drive up to date, and/or if you need to install a lot of program packages, it is better to install Ubuntu (like into an internal drive) but to a USB drive. Such a system is portable between computers, but not as portable as a live or persistent live system.

It can be a good idea to install an Ubuntu community flavour with a light desktop environment, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu, because the communication is slower to a USB pendrive than to an internal hard disk drive or solid state drive. (A USB 3 SSD is fast alternative.)

Comment: I have been doing some experimenting on splitting a casper-rw file into a casper-rw file plus home-rw file, and doing similar with a casper-rw partition. This can be handy for upgrading a persistent drive say from 16.04 to 18.04. The home-rw file/partition can be reused after version upgrade but the casper-rw file/partition can not. I am not sure yet about permissions. I think copy casper-rw then rename to home-rw, and delete everything but home folder. Then delete home folder in casper-rw.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, I checked the details and edited the answer with details how to copy `/home` from `casper-rw`to `home-rw`- I did it by converting the `usbdata` partition to `home-rw` with the `ext4` file system in a persistent live drive made with mkusb.

Comment: I think you can move the home folder from casper-rw to the a home-rw partition. This makes it easier to "version upgrade" a persistent drive.