# ubuntu 16.04 install creates no boot/efi/

Tags: 16.04, grub2, uefi, grub-legacy

Installing ubuntu 16.04 from a bootable USB generates an unbootable system.

Upon inspection through the USB install, I see that the installed OS has no /boot/efi partition nor files.

Is the ubuntu installation performing installation in legacy mode? If so, how can this be explicitly changed?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037843/installing-ubuntu-without-touching-windows/1037872#1037872 for screenshots  of installation to figure out if you installed in UEFI or Legacy mode. Please edit your question and include more details about how you installed Ubuntu. Did you install side by side Windows (dual boot) or erase everything and install, or did "something else"?

Comment: Also see [How to create UEFI only bootable- USB live-media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media)

Comment: Erased everything. There was only a previous ubuntu install. Have also installed pre setting to legacy or uefi. No difference

Comment: Sometimes when you select the USB from the boot menu you will see two menu entries for USB, one may say "Boot from USB" and other may say "UEFI boot from USB". If you see two USB boot options, then select the one with UEFI.