# Ubuntu installed alongside Windows on 2nd drive doesn't boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu onto my 2nd drive (the main drive has Windows 10 on it) but there is no way for me to boot it from it. I tried changing the boot order but that didn't work. Then I tried unplugging my SSD with Windows and only leaving the other disk but it wouldn't boot anything.

Solved!

Boot repair helped me. I removed grub from the system and then installed in on both disks and now I get into the grub menu when booting.

Thank you all for help!

Comment: What is the brand/model of your computer?

Comment: @Jakub Michálek Please collect the model number from the sticker which also has the serial number (don't want serial #, just model#). Please also run `lshw | grep -v "loop"` in a terminal window. Then, click [edit] and add that with the make and model# to your original question. Please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Post link above in your original question.

Comment: See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037843/installing-ubuntu-without-touching-windows/1037872#1037872) to work around a possible bug.

Comment: @Jakub Please remove what you have done from your question and post an answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to disable the *Windows Fast Startup* function?
This has caused me the same problem in the past. Try running this command from the Windows cmd Prompt:

```
Shutdown.exe -s -t 00
```

It will shutdown windows completely and if you still don't get the grub menu, then try setting grub as the boot manager for Windows with this cmd:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling secure boot in your computer’s BIOS. If you didn’t install Ubuntu with an EFI partition, you may need to enable the legacy boot option in BIOS.

Comment: I tried to do this but when i go to the advanced options there is no option called UEFI Firmware Settings and i don't know where else i can change it.

Comment: Re-install Ubuntu and this time, add an EFI System partition 100mb is size.

Comment: I Have actually done this. I added 300mb of space for the EFI. So that's done