# Ubuntu and Windows on different drives

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows, ssd, drive

Dual boot but the os on different drives. Is it okay or would I have some booting problems?

Should the windows be on ssd and ubuntu installed on hdd? Or there will be a specific problem? Is it okay to dual boot like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu without touching Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037843/installing-ubuntu-without-touching-windows)

Comment: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI See also this bug: Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Ubuntu Installer uses wrong bootloader location for USB/sdb UEFI installs 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1173457

Answer (score 0):

It is better to install OSes into SSD if your SSD disk size is sufficient, because of both Windows and Ubuntu will perform better.

Use HDD as a user data storage.

But that's probably OK to use them on different drives. Only at the end of installation specify grub installation target disk you're using to install Ubuntu on.

It's not mandatory, but better in case if you'll replace your other drive in the future.

To avoid issues with booting, prepare yourself by reading guides and instructions. Make backups. Use manual disk configuration in case of Ubuntu installation.

Comment: so it does not take more booting time.