# Unallocated Partition is not showing while installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-mate, boot-partition

I have a new Dell desktop which has 512 GB SSD. Now I have inserted an additional 1 TB HDD and from this HDD I have unallocated 100 GB. Please check the screenshot attached. But while installing Ubuntu(along with windows 10, dual boot) It is not showing this 100 Gb partition, instead, it shows the whole 1 TB HDD along with other Partition(from 512 GB SSD). Can anyone help me out?

[image]

Installing Step:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. What do you mean by "It is not showing this 100 GB partition."? Please take a picture of the installation screen and add to your question. Are you using the advanced "Something Else" or the "Install Ubuntu along side Windows" option?

Comment: Don't use Windows to create or prepare partitions for Ubuntu.  Instead, use the "Disks" application from the live session booting from installation media.

Comment: You never made a partition in the unallocated empty space. After making a partition, you then need to make a filesystem.  Then the filesystem should show up.

Comment: @user68186 Thank You. I have updated the question with the image. Please check the same. I have choosen something else and got this. Can You help me out?

Comment: @Nmath How can I do this? Can I get steps OR Links?

Comment: @ubfan1 How can I do this? Can I get steps OR Links?

Comment: I can work on an answer sometime this week, but to be honest the application is fairly self explanatory. Moreso than the disk tools in Windows. Why don't you open it and see if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @ubfan I disagree completely with your advice. **unpartitioned free space** will make the installation easier, especially for a dual boot config.  This is how you get the "Install Alongside Windows" option, assuming that use of EFI/BIOS mode is consistent.  If you create a partition you don't get that option.  And there's also room for user error since many file systems are incompatible with Ubuntu root file system.  Let the installer make the partitions, you just have to give it unpartitioned free space

Comment: If you choose the "Install along side Windows" option, the installer should find the unallocated 100 GB and install Ubuntu there (after confirming with you). See the [easy installation section of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248299/how-do-i-uninstall-reinstall-ubuntu-on-hdd-from-separate-os-windows-10-operatin/1248318#1248318).

Comment: If you shutdown Windows with the "Fast Boot" option enabled,  Windows makes NTFS volumes look funny. Reboot Windows, turn off "Fast Boot" (I don't know how) and retry.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation   The Something Else way to add a new partition is to click on the "+" at the bottom of the disk screen.  This way you can make partition(s) of the size you select.  As was pointed out, selecting the "Alongside" will automatically make a 100G root partition for you.  @Nmath my earlier comment was a description, not advice.  The OP apparently was in the installer, had  already selected "Something Else", and was wondering where the "partition" was.