# Help Avoiding Ubuntu Installer Bug where Grub installs to wrong Disk

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

There's a bug with ubuntu installers where it puts grub on the wrong disk (have had this problem before and had to manually redo everthing)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
I'm again in a same situation. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 on my computer. I have 2 disks.
/dev/sda has windows
/dev/sdb will have ubuntu. I'm at the installer part where i select "something else" and have made an efi partition on /dev/sdb1 (1gb) and /dev/sdb2 (the rest) will be EXT4 and have the mount point.
I'm in the middle of the installer and according to the workaround I'm supposed to type:

```
sudo umount /target/boot/efi
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /target/boot/efi
```

however there is no /target/boot/efi to unmount. I'm worried if I don't run these commands it'll screw up /dev/sda again like it did the last time. Anyone know if there's another point in the installer when this happens? I'm afraid to push the "Install Now" button without being able to complete this step.
Thanks!!

Comment: You may also want to read [Installing Ubuntu without touching Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037843/installing-ubuntu-without-touching-windows) and [Dual Booting win 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on two separate physical ssds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds).

Comment: I think that if you unplug the windows drive, before installing Ubuntu on the other drive you can't go wrong.

Comment: How come Canonical Support aren't fixing this dangerous bug ? I had to get Timeshift to drag me out of the muck yet again on this one - all coming from the simple task of creating a full install of Ubuntu 21.04 on a USB stick so I could look at Westland and iwd 1.12. After trying to reboot back into my 20.04 in my (main) SSD drive, I found I couldn't boot *anything* without the damn USB stuck in the PC . . . After a Timeshift restore, a boot from the SSD alone was restored. When the USB was reinserted, the order of the Ubuntu versions is inverted with the 20.04 LTS version on top as default.