# Bootloader installs on wrong disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, ssd

I'm trying to Dualboot Ubuntu with Windows but always fail. I have 1 NVMe M.2 drive (`Samsung 970 EVO 250 GB`) and 1 SATA SSD (`Patriot Burst 120 GB`). I would like to install Windows on the NVMe and Ubuntu on the SATA SSD.

The problem is, whatever I do, the bootloader of the secondly installed system goes onto the drive with the firstly installed system. For example, if I install Windows onto the NVMe, everything is fine until I try to install the Ubuntu onto the second drive. After the installation, GRUB goes onto the NVMe even though I selected the SSD for it's installation. If I install Ubuntu first, it's vice versa. Windows bootloader installs onto the Ubuntu drive.

This issue is making my life harder as I can't, for example, use VirtualBox in any of those systems.

I'm running:

- ASUS TUF Z370-PLUS GAMING - Intel Z370
- Intel Core i5-8600K
- 16 GB of RAM

**Any answer will be appreciated!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu without touching Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037843/installing-ubuntu-without-touching-windows)

Comment: Pay special attention to the **bug alert** and **work around** sections.

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs griub to first drive seen when UEFI. Do you have ESP on SSD? If so you can reinstall grub, manually or with Boot-Repair. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive. Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive. (I have not had that work, but others have.)

Comment: *"the bootloader of the secondly installed system goes onto the drive with the firstly installed system.*" - it's **supposed** to be this way on EFI systems.  You should only have one EFI (boot) partition.

Answer (score 0):

if grub did the right thing in the wrong place, tell grub where to install after successful generation of config:

1. sudo update-grub
2. sudo grub-install -v /dev/yourdrive

2 is drive, not partition (normally).

You may do that in more than one location!!
Do it on a USB-memory-stick as a backup as well.

This applies to non-UEFI, I avoid UEFI and can not tell you about UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I installed Ubuntu to a USB stick, however, grub installed on the primary windows disk that I really didn't want to touch. I tried this before (with EndeavourOS) and it didn't do that.

the Ubuntu installer nicely warns you about what disk you are about to wipe and format but it says nothing about changing an existing boot record (or UEFI partition), it should warn about that too imho.