# 16.04 installed on USB not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi, 18.04

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Sandisk Cruzer 8gb flash drive. I used a PNY bootable USB to install from, all running off my MacBook Pro (Early 2015, OSX 10.13.4).

I booted into the PNY, selected the "Install Ubuntu" option in the boot loader, then installed to the Sandisk. I also was prompted to choose a location to install the boot loader, so I installed it on the Sandisk. Everything completed without crashing, and I was prompted to reboot in order to use the installation.

rEFInd doesn't recognize the Sandisk at all, much less as bootable. However, when I go to re-install Ubuntu on the Sandisk, there's already an Ubuntu installation there.

What's going on? Have I missed something or skipped an important step? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In UEFI mode, when you try to install to an external drive, actually to any second drive (second to the main internal drive `/dev/sda`, the UEFI bootloader will be put (or merged) into an EFI system partition (ESP) in `/dev/sda`. You can prevent this, if you can disconnect or unplug the internal drive. Otherwise you can copy the necessary directories and files manually (but it is a little tricky). Maybe the following link can help, [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)