# Does a cloned disk run on two separate machine with different configuration?

Tags: disk, restore

I can "Create Partition Image" on my Ubuntu Desktop machine anytime using Disks Utilities. And I can also "Restore Partition Image" to my machine anytime if anything goes wrong.

My question is this; can I "Restore Partition Image" of my machine to another machine that has different configuration? And will all the drivers and other programs work perfectly?

Other than that disk cloning would be useless and sometimes a total waste of time.

Comment: In theory as long as the hardware is compatible and you know how to configure grub yes. The drivers are in the kernel and loaded as needed as modules.  See the kernel module documentation as needed for details.

Comment: Not only in theory, but also in real life, if the computers are not too different. It will often work (I have done it many times). You should avoid proprietary drivers (typically for graphics and wifi). So for example if one computer has new and powerful nvidia graphics, there might be problems. This link describes how to make an installed system in an external drive, that can run in several computers, [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. This question is not a duplicate. Let me expand my question a little bit more. I am currently using a MBR partitioned disk. Can I restore this image on a GPT partitioned disk? Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.