# Ubuntu Usb persistence problem with Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, software-center, ubuntu-store

Good morning everyone,

I would like to know if you could help, the problem is the following :

Yesterday i tried to install "Atom" and "Gimp" from Ubuntu Software, both downloaded correctly, but when i lunch the programs they do not respond, i mean they do not open at all, it seems that they are only loading for few second but that's it.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with Usb  persistence.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that the programs are installed correctly and completely? Please run the following command line, edit your original question to show the output (of the command). Indent each line of the output 4 spaces to render it as 'code', `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gimp`

Comment: After installing again, try launching gimp again. Note the *exact* time. If it fails again, please edit your question with the relevant error messages in /var/log/syslog from the seconds before and after that time.

Comment: How much drive space is free in `/cow`? Please check with the command `df -h`, edit your original question to show the output (of the command). Indent each line of the output 4 spaces to render it as 'code'

Comment: 4 Gb of freespace @sudodus

Comment: @sudodus it say E : Unable to locate the package (Gimp or Atom) Although i'm seeing them

Comment: You must activate the repository 'universe' for the gimp package to be found and installed. I don't know where to find Atom (yet). See my answer below.

Comment: What `atom` program and corresponding package do you want? There seems to be more than one, that are available in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79947/discussion-between-sudodus-and-jacopoburelli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I can verify that `gimp` can be installed and that it works in a persistent live Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** [family flavour, Lubuntu].

[image]

My test system was installed into an old hard disk drive, that I have connected via a USB3 to SATA adapter. I used [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create the persistent live system.

I have run `gimp` also in standard Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it works also in a USB pendrive, if there is enough free space in the `casper-rw` file or partition. You must activate the repository 'universe' for the `gimp` package to be found and installed,

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

---

**Edit:** Before giving up your current persistent live system, try to reboot.

- If no luck, maybe it would be best to create a fresh persistent live system with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), or
- if your USB drive is big and fast enough to [create an installed system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312) in it, installed like into an internal drive but into a USB drive. Such a system can be portable enough (but not as portable as a persistent live system), and it is more flexible and stable, when we talk about installing program packages.

Comment: Last time i enable universe the usb crashed after reloaded it,so i’m a bit scared, any idea why ?

Comment: You need universe, if you want to install gimp. I have no bad experience from installing it (and it is there by default in the Ubuntu community flavours). Maybe your bad experience was because you had some manually installed program package, that came into conflict with the standard version from universe.

Comment: “ ‘universe’ distribution component is already enabled for all sources” it says

Comment: OK, it means that it was installed during an earlier attempt to install gimp or some other program package. What is the output after running `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gimp` ? Where and how do you 'see' atom and gimp?

Comment: E : Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock -open (11: Resoyrce temporarily unavailable)

Comment: E: Unable to lock directory /var... (same from above)

Comment: You must turn off the Software Center before you try the command line. The lock is there to keep the programs from interfering with each other.

Comment: W : Target Sources (main/sorce/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and .....

Comment: Let us [**continue this discussion in chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79946/discussion-between-sudodus-and-jacopoburelli).

Comment: Updated the packages and got Kernel panic

Comment: @jacopoburelli, you disappeared from the chat room. I hope you did not give up. I think we can solve this problem. Anyway, I will look for input from you ...