# Unable to MBR boot Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I got a new motherboard/CPU, reinstalled Windows 10 (Legacy/MBR).

I want to install Ubuntu however I cannot boot my USB disk as MBR Ubuntu: if I pick Install or Live I get a Kernel panic with messages re: the Bios.

I can boot/run the USB disk as UEFI - and then installation fails because it tries to install GRUB2 as UEFI and the disk is MBR.

Is there anyway to boot UEFI USB disk and install/setup MBR GRUB2?

Any ideas on why MBR Ubuntu boot fails (MSI X470)?

I have rebuilt the USB disk 3 times (once in case the distro was corrupt, and once after updating to Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.8.2. No help.

Comment: how did you prepare the USB as bootable disk? Rufus or other programme?

Comment: I understand that you want to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows. Do you want to install Ubuntu into the same drive (HDD or SSD) as Windows? Or into another drive (internal or external)? It might be a good idea to install a [persistent live Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf) or [installed system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312) into a fast USB 3 pendrive or USB 3 connected SSD.

Comment: I used Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.8.2 to prepare the Usb Disk as MBR.

Comment: I am installing both on a 128GB SSD - (100GB Windows, 28GB Ubuntu). I had this same dual boot setup on my prior MB/CPU (same disk, Windows/Ubuntu versions).