# Install Ubuntu on external HDD while also having Windows on an internal SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, windows, hard-drive

I want to try Ubuntu again, (I just check have the new stuff new version have 18.04), it's almost 1 year since I stopped using Ubuntu. Now I have a new computer. It has a  128GB SSD including all the programs I need for work on Windows. There remains less than 24GB, of course the best (and most simple) would be to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, using grub to manage the boot, but with only 24GB it isn't enough, and won't be possible.

I have a 320GB WD external HDD, I thought installing Ubuntu on it would be easy.

The first attempt failed to install grub on it. Then I read I should made boot partition, because is recommended, and also turn on internet would help the installation, (which I didn't).

I also read in a tutorial for installing Ubuntu on an external HDD that the installation would mess up Windows 10 boot, but how and why? This is the main reason I'm asking this question. Since I don't want to go through all the fixing windows boot stuff. Why will installing Ubuntu on another will mess up windows boot?

I'm chosing my external HDD for "Device for bootloader installation" which is the `/dev/sdb` (my WD external HDD) not my actual SSD where I have Windows installed (which is `/dev/sda`).

Comment: 1. Standard installation: It makes no difference, if you install Ubuntu alongside Windows in the same drive or in another drive, or to be correct, in a partition or two in such a drive; 2. But if you do not want to touch the internal drive, you should unplug it and install Ubuntu into the external drive according to the following link, [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

Comment: @sudodus, a question, since my laptop it's an APU, it's the same if I disable my SDD in the BIOS? so I don't have to unplug it (it's complicated)

Comment: It should. Easy to test by turning off drive in UEFI settings. Then boot Ubuntu live installer in live mode and see what drive(s) it shows. You may need total cold reboot as if UEFI fast boot is on, it assumes no changes. But change in UEFI should cause full reboot, not warm reboot.

Comment: Yes, +1 to @oldfred's advice :-)