# Edit Debian USB disk

Tags: usb, debian, usb-installation, debian-installer

I need edit USB stick disk by adding a file with firmware to my wifi card and lan card when I try install I see error.

How to change permission to add files into USB boot disk working on UBUNTU 17.10??

ISO downloaded from this source:
[iso-dvd/](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/8.11.0/amd64/iso-dvd/)

Disk created by UBUNTU Startup Disk Creator

> df -h:

```
/dev/sdc1       3.8G  3.8G     0 100% /media/xxx/Debian 8.11.0 amd64 1
```

> sudo lsblk -f

```
sdc  iso966 Debian 8.11.0 amd64 1
│                                2018-06-23-13-24-25-00               
├─sdc1
│    iso966 Debian 8.11.0 amd64 1
│                                2018-06-23-13-24-25-00               
/media/xxx
└─sdc2
 vfat   Debian 8.11.0 amd64 1
                             675A-A891
```

> udo parted -ls

```
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 
bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Model: Generic Mass-Storage (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 7822MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Comment: 1. Does the target USB drive contain a Debian live or installed system? 2. How was it created (with which tool/method)? 3. Please run the following commands to show the partition structure, `df -h` and `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo parted -ls`; 4. Edit your original question to add the output of the commands. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code'.

Comment: @sudodus: done what next?

Comment: Debian 8? Jessie? (Not really about Ubuntu!) You should just download "Unofficial non-free images including firmware packages" which has firmware included. https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/

Comment: I want to use 8.11 because my computer is old. And 8.11 should be fine for this device. So how to add this firmware to install boot USB stick?

Answer (score 2):

Compare this line

```
sdc  iso966 Debian 8.11.0 amd64 1
                                 2018-06-23-13-24-25-00
```

with the correspoding line, when I loop mount my similar iso file

```
sudo mount -o loop debian-live-8.8.0-amd64-standard.iso /mnt/lp1

$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL                         UUID                    MOUNTPOINT
loop0  iso9660  Debian jessie 20170506-14:26  2017-05-06-13-27-04-00  mnt/lp1
```

You see that there is an iso 9660 partition structure and file system, which is typical for a system, cloned from a hybrid iso file. The iso 9660 system is read-only by nature, and cannot be modified.

So you need to use an [extracting tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb) (not a cloning tool), if you want to be able to 
modify it. But I am not sure that a live or persistent live system will be able to take advantage of the firmware you want.

Instead I suggest that you create an installed system in your USB drive (installed like into an internal drive), and install the firmware (and maybe drivers and other software) into that system. See this link (and modify it to take into consideration, that it is not an Ubuntu system, or simply try the newest Ubuntu system, 18.04.1 LTS).

[Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)